# Element-wise maximum value for two lists

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given two Mathematica sets of data such as

```
data1 = {0, 1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 15, 6, 5, 2, 0};
data2 = {0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 16, 5, 5, 2, 1};
```

how can I create a set giving me the maximum value of the two lists, i.e. how to obtain

```
data3 = {0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 16, 6, 5, 2, 1};
```

?

Comment: you looking for i.e. c# code?

Comment: Please take a look at this site, specifically for Mathematica questions http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 4):

```
data1 = {0, 1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 15, 6, 5, 2, 0};
data2 = {0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 16, 5, 5, 2, 1};
Max /@ Transpose[{data1, data2}]
(* {0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 16, 6, 5, 2, 1} *)
```

Comment: BTW `/@`is a shorthand for [Map](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html)

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is to use the [MapThread](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html) function:

```
data3 = MapThread[Max, {data1, data2}]
```

belisarius solution however is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest, though not the fastest:

```
Inner[Max,data1,data2,List]
```

Comment: Hmm, 3 function calls *vs* 3 in belisarius' answer *vs* 2 in sakra's.  I think that all 3 are in the same equivalence class for simplicity.